# Jquery processing a multiple selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is something I really should have learned long ago, but I somehow never did.

```
var productDivs = $('#HomeNewProducts .ProductList li');
```

So here is a simple line that selects multiple li's and its children. Now, let's say I want to extract a link from each of these elements to use it after to link an element I'm appending.

```
var link = $('#HomeNewProducts .ProductList li .ProductDetails a').attr('href');
productDivs.append('<a href=\"' . link . '\"><img src="#" /></a> ' );
```

Comment: Question is unclear: "Select `a` link from `each` of its elements." How many links could be extracted? How could you attach multiple links to "an element" you are appending?  Please clarify, and create [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: consider rephrasing this "to use it after to link an element I'm appending", using punctuations would be good idea. please state your question in a separate line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is good for extracting a collection of properties from a collection:

```
// get .`attr('href')` from each element
var links = $('#HomeNewProducts .ProductList li .ProductDetails a');
var hrefs = links.map(function(link) { 
    return $(link).attr("href"); 
});
```

But since it looks like you want to iterate over a set of elements, and append something to each, I guess you want JQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$('#HomeNewProducts .ProductList li').each(function(index, element) {
    // find child link of the current element
    var link = $(element).find(".ProductDetails a").attr('href');

    // append to the current element
    $(element).append('<a href=\"' . link . '\"><img src="#" /></a> ' );
});
```

[Here's a simplified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HKyjj/) of the general idea.

Comment: Thanks. I had looked into the .each() documentation but didn't realize it could be used in this way.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var link = $('#HomeNewProducts .ProductList li .ProductDetails a').attr('href');
productDivs.append('<a href=\"' + link + '\"><img src="#" /></a> ' );
```

The plus signs should properly insert the `link` variable into the string.

Comment: You are right. Javascript is +'s for conactenation. I was thinking in PHP

Comment: It happens, I'm sure. Though be sure to look at the other answers as well. I think they cover it better than I.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already cached the `li` elements in `productDivs` us it when searching for further descendants.

Then use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) to iterate over a group of selected elements

```
var productDivs = $('#HomeNewProducts .ProductList li');
var link = productDivs.find('.ProductDetails a').each(function(){
   // do the appending from here
   // this.href refers to the current link

   productDivs.append('<a href=\"' + this.href + '\"><img src="#" /></a>' );
});
```